# iOS6: how to change the cross dissolve from displaying black in between transition

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5, uistoryboardsegue, uiviewanimationtransition

I am using the storyboard segue cross dissolve for my transition but during the transitions its has a greyish effect.

Is there a way to amend / remove this so that i can add a colour to match my vie backgrounds so the transitions are not to obvious.